# Игра "Виселица" не работает коректно

Tags: javascript

Игра работает, но игрок выигрывает если он угадывает всего лишь одну любую букву, что не правильно, потому как игрок должен отгадатать все буквы в слове, что бы выиграть.

```js
//создаем массив со словами
var words = [
"оладушек"
];
//выбираем случайное слово
var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
//создаем итоговый масив 
var answerArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
 answerArray[i] = "_"
}

var remainingLetters = words.length

//игровой цикл
while (remainingLetters > 0) {
//показываем состояние игры
alert(answerArray.join(" "));
//запрашиваем вариант ответа 
var guess = prompt("Угадайте букву, или нажмите Отменя для выхода из игры.");
if (guess === null) {
 //выходим из игрового цикла
 break;
} else if (guess.length !== 1) {
 alert("Пожалуйста, введите одиночную букву");
} else {
 //обновляем состояние игры 
 for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
  if (word[j] === guess) {
   answerArray[j] = guess;
   remainingLetters--;
  }
 }
}
//конец игрового цикла 
}
//отображаем ответ и подздравляем игрока
alert(answerArray.join(" "));
alert("Отлично! Было загадано слово " + word);
```

Comment: `remainingLetters` изначально равен 1, так как ты записываешь туда не длину слова а длину массива.

Comment: напиши вот так `words[0].length`

Answer (score 0):

```
var worIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
var word = words[wordIndex];

while (word.length > 0) {

  ...

    if (word[j] === guess) {
        word = word.replace(guess, '');
    }

  ...

alert("Отлично! Было загадано слово " + words[wordIndex]);
```